# Weird Wags Java Program 213a. Using several if else statements

Tags: java, computer-science

You just started working as a programmer.  You've agreed to the following compensation package.

•   You are paid $30 an hour.
•   You earn an extra $25.50 an hour for any part of a day where you work more than 8 hours.
•   You earn an extra $15 an hour for hours beyond 40 in any one week.
•   You also earn a 125% bonus on any amount you earn for working on Saturday, and a 50% bonus for working Sunday.

Your input file will be the number of hours you worked each day in the week beginning with Sunday.  You need to write a program that will continue processing the file to calculate your gross pay for each week worked until the end of file is reached.  Each line of input will consist of one weeks hours (7 integers per line, each less than or equal to 24).  Output the gross pay with a dollar sign rounded to the nearest penny for each week worked.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class prog213a
{
public static void main (String args [])
{
    Scanner inFile = null; //setting scanned file as null

    double weeklyPay=0,sunPay=0, monPay=0, tuesPay=0, wedPay=0, thurPay=0, friPay=0, satPay=0;

    try
    {
        inFile =new Scanner(new File("prog213a.dat")); //reading file
    }
    catch(Exception e) //if file doesn't exist
    {
        System.out.println("File not found"); //output that file doesn't exist
        System.exit (0); //exit program
    }

    while (inFile.hasNext())
    {
        final int sunHours = inFile.nextInt();
        final int monHours = inFile.nextInt();
        final int tuesHours = inFile.nextInt();
        final int wedHours = inFile.nextInt();
        final int thurHours = inFile.nextInt();
        final int friHours = inFile.nextInt();
        final int satHours = inFile.nextInt();
        final int weeklyHours = monHours + tuesHours + wedHours + thurHours + friHours;
        if(sunHours>8){
            sunPay=((sunHours-8)*55.50)+240;
        }
        else{
            sunPay= sunHours*30;
        }
        if(monHours>8){
            monPay=((monHours-8)*55.50)+240;
        }
        else{
            monPay= monHours*30;
        }
        if(tuesHours>8){
            tuesPay=((tuesHours-8)*55.50)+240;
        }
        else{
            tuesPay= tuesHours*30;
        }
        if(wedHours>8){
            wedPay=((wedHours-8)*55.50)+240;
        }
        else{
            wedPay= wedHours*30;
        }
        if(thurHours>8){
            thurPay=((thurHours-8)*55.50)+240;
        }
        else{
            thurPay= thurHours*30;
        }
        if(friHours>8){
            friPay=((friHours-8)*55.50)+240;
        }
        else{
            friPay= friHours*30;
        }
        if(satHours>8){
            satPay=((satHours-8)*55.50)+240;
        }
        if(weeklyHours>40){
            weeklyPay=((weeklyHours-40)*45)+1200;
        }
        System.out.print(sunPay);
    }
  }
}
```

I've written this code so far, but when I went to test the program to see if it is even getting the right for sunday pay I got this "295.5210.0180.0" 
I need help getting this code fixed so that it fits the parameters and outputs the correct answer.

Data file:

9 8 10 8 9 9 5

7 8 8 8 0 8 9

6 10 5 0 0 0 0

Comment: Homework questions are considered off topic.

Comment: Please read [mcve] and make sure you read the "How to debug small programs" document linked at the bottom of the page.

Comment: @JasonD I thought this website was to help programmers who needed assistance with their code, or am I wrong?

Comment: It is, but the way you've asked the question is not in a form that people here can help with. You've posted the original question and your entire solution; but you've ended your question to us with "I need help getting this code fixed". As you saw in the link that Adrian posted above, please try to cut down your question to be small enough that it zeros in on the part of your code that you believe isn't working after you've fully debugged it yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix the code myself.

```
    Scanner inFile = null; //setting scanned file as null

    double weeklyPay=0,sunPay=0, monPay=0, tuesPay=0, wedPay=0, thurPay=0, friPay=0, satPay=0, overPay=0; //initializing variables
    int weekNumber=1; //which week it is

    DecimalFormat twodigits= new DecimalFormat("0.00"); //formating numbers

    try
    {
        inFile =new Scanner(new File("prog213a.dat")); //reading file 
    }
    catch(Exception e) //if file doesn't exist
    {
        System.out.println("File not found"); //output that file doesn't exist
        System.exit (0); //exit program
    }

    while (inFile.hasNextLine()) //while the file has a next line of data
    {
        System.out.println("Week " + weekNumber + ": "); //header

        int sunHours = inFile.nextInt();  //getting the hours for each day
        int monHours = inFile.nextInt();
        int tuesHours = inFile.nextInt();
        int wedHours = inFile.nextInt();
        int thurHours = inFile.nextInt();
        int friHours = inFile.nextInt();
        int satHours = inFile.nextInt();
        int weeklyHours = monHours + tuesHours + wedHours + thurHours + friHours; //weekly hours is summation of hours

        System.out.println(sunHours + " " + monHours + " " + tuesHours + " " + wedHours + " " + thurHours + " " + friHours + " " + satHours); //output

        //calculating daily pay depending on the specifications

        if(sunHours>8) 
            sunPay=(((sunHours-8)*55.50)+240)*2.25;
        else
            sunPay=(sunHours*30)*2.25;

        if(monHours>8)
            monPay=((monHours-8)*55.50)+240;
        else
            monPay= monHours*30;

        if(tuesHours>8)
            tuesPay=((tuesHours-8)*55.50)+240;
        else
            tuesPay= tuesHours*30;

        if(wedHours>8)
            wedPay=((wedHours-8)*55.50)+240;
        else
            wedPay= wedHours*30;

        if(thurHours>8)
            thurPay=((thurHours-8)*55.50)+240;
        else
            thurPay= thurHours*30;

        if(friHours>8)
            friPay=((friHours-8)*55.50)+240;
        else
            friPay= friHours*30;

        if(satHours>8)
            satPay=(((satHours-8)*55.50)+240)*1.5;
        else
            satPay= (satHours*30)*1.5;


        if(weeklyHours>40){
            overPay=(weeklyHours-40)*45; //pay if weekly hours are over 40
            weeklyPay=(sunPay + monPay + tuesPay + wedPay + thurPay + friPay + satPay + overPay); //pay including over pay
            System.out.println(twodigits.format(weeklyPay));//output
        }
        else{
            weeklyPay=(sunPay+monPay+tuesPay+wedPay+thurPay+friPay+satPay); //pay if hours is less than 40
            System.out.println(twodigits.format(weeklyPay)); //output
        }

        weekNumber++; //increments the week number
        System.out.println(); //blank line
    }
```